# Clear content of view in Titanium

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I have a view that contains tableview that contains data loaded from web i.e various places and in another topview i have a data pick dialog that can set km for radius. So on changing value I want to clear data in tableview and load new data according to radius selected by the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just create an empty array to clear the data, and set it to your new data array. Something like:

```
tableview.data = []; // Clears the array
tableview.data = [newArray]; // Sets the new data
```

Comment: Thanks for the valuable reply. I haven't tried your answer but below code works for me well.                                           `tablearray=[];//clears the array`